# Java - After close() on stream or channel returned, does it finished all the job?

Tags: java, linux, io, filesystems, testng

When writing byte transfer related **Java** code, on **linux**, got some doubt.

### Code

**FileChannelTest.java**: (*a TestNG testing class*)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * FileChannel test
 * 
 * @author eric
 * @date Sep 1, 2012 7:16:10 PM
 */
@Test(singleThreaded = true)
public class FileChannelTest {
    private String sourcePath = "/home/eric/desktop/a.zip";
    private String targetPath = "/tmp/a.zip";

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testCopyViaTransfer" })
    public void testCopyViaBuffer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        copyViaBuffer(new File(sourcePath), new File(targetPath));
        // delay();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCopyViaTransfer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        copyViaTransfer(new File(sourcePath), new File(targetPath));
        delay();
    }

    // make thread sleep a while, so that reduce effect to subsequence operation if any shared resource,
    private void delay(long milliseconds) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    }

    private void delay() throws InterruptedException {
        delay(500);
    }

    /**
     * copy file via buffer,
     * 
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param targetFile
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void copyViaBuffer(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

        // get channel,
        FileChannel readFc = fis.getChannel();
        FileChannel writeFc = fos.getChannel();

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 32); // 32Kb

        // copy via buffer,
        while (readFc.read(buf) != -1) {
            buf.flip(); // prepare for write,
            writeFc.write(buf);
            buf.clear(); // prepare for read,
        }

        // close
        readFc.close();
        writeFc.close();

        fis.close();
        fos.close();

        System.out.printf("[%s] total time: [%d ms]\n", "copy via buffer", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }

    /**
     * copy file via transfer,
     * 
     * @param sourceFile
     * @param targetFile
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void copyViaTransfer(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

        // get channel,
        FileChannel readFc = fis.getChannel();
        FileChannel writeFc = fos.getChannel();

        // transfer
        readFc.transferTo(0, readFc.size(), writeFc);

        // close
        readFc.close();
        writeFc.close();

        fis.close();
        fos.close();

        System.out.printf("[%s] total time: [%d ms]\n", "copy via transfer", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }
}
```

### Execute result:

(*Using `Java 8`, on 64 bit `linux 3.x`, `ext4` file system, with 4 cpu, if that matters*)

*(1)* If **enable** the delay in `testCopyViaTransfer()`:

```
[copy via transfer] total time: [11 ms]
[copy via buffer] total time: [16 ms]
```

*(2)* If **disable** the delay in `testCopyViaTransfer()`:

```
[copy via transfer] total time: [11 ms]
[copy via buffer] total time: [173 ms]
```

You can see the execution of second method differs huge, **16 ms** vs **173 ms**, that's the doubt.

The code use a single thread, so the `close()` of `testCopyViaTransfer()` already returned, when `testCopyViaBuffer()` start to execute.

I also tested that, it's the target file matters, because when use different target file for the two methods, then second method won't be slow no matter call `delay()` or not.

### The questions are:

- After a `close()` on `stream` or `channel` have returned (especially for the case of local file, not remote socket), have it finished all the job about underling resource? Or, is the underling resource ready to be used again?
- If yes, then what cause the difference in 2 test, is that os (kernel) related mechanism, that Java have no control on ?
- What analysis tools are available to check issues like this, if any.

Comment: Yes, it's synchronous operation on both FileChannel and AsynchronousFileChannel.

Comment: @Matt You mean the `delay()` doesn't matter I guess, I am wondering why the testing result differs so hugely.